# plotting an array of dataset with ListPlot Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a set of datapoints such as (THIS IS AN EXAMPLE)

```
 val=4; (*this value is calculated before in the program, so it not known a priori*)
 x={0,1,2,3};
 data=Table[0, {val}];
 data[[1]] = {1,5,6,8};
 data[[2]] = {9,7,1,3};
 data[[3]] = {3,4,5,6};
 data[[4]] = {2,2,4,6};
```

Now I can plot each of these data with ListPlot as

```
 ListPlot[Transpose[{x,data[[1]]}]]
```

and if I want to plot more than one I can do

```
 ListPlot[{Transpose[{x, data[[1]]}], Transpose[{x, data[[2]]}]}]
```

but how can I plot all of them in one code single line, by considering that val is calculated before in the program?

Is there a way to do something like

```
 For[i = 1, i < val + 1, i++, ListPlot[Transpose[{x,data[i]}]]......]
```

having a single graph with all x-y curves?

Indeed I would like a static picture of

```
 Manipulate[ListPlot[Transpose[{x, data[[i]]}]], {i, 1, val,1}]
```

Thanks

Virgilio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "do the same thing" to every element of a list. That should tell you to think of using Map. Your list is named data and each element is your four element sublist. If you look at the help page for Map it shows you need to think up a function that does what you need to do to each individual sublist. You have already understood that you need to use Transpose with x and your sublist so that tells you your function and you are almost there. The result of Map will be a list of all those results. So

```
In[1]:= x = {0, 1, 2, 3};
data = {{1, 5, 6, 8}, {9, 7, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 2, 4, 6}};
ListPlot[Map[Transpose[{x, #}] &, data], Joined -> True]

Out[3]= ...FourOverlaidPlotsSnipped...
```

Go through that a word at a time until you can really understand the thinking that was done to be able to write that. You will use this idea again and again if you keep using Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give the cleanest method is to use `DataRange`:

```
data = {{1, 5, 6, 8}, {9, 7, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 2, 4, 6}};

ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 3}]
```

[image]

---

Please ask your future questions on the dedicated *Mathematica* StackExchange site:

[image]